# What is the lightest Java Virtual Machine ever? (except KVM)

Tags: java, jvm

I'd like to install Java on a Psion 5MX with GNU/Linux 16MB RAM machine, will it be possible?

Unfortunatly, ["KVM must be installed by the manufacturer"](http://www.java.com/en/download/faq/5000080100.xml).

What I want is to be able to is to write basic Java code, test and sketch simple algorithms. 
Important notes: I don't need the graphic part since I'll only use the console (no graphic server) but this will be inside a Debian.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please give us more details about the machine, besides the OS and the memory. Also give us details on what you hope to accomplish with Java on such an underpowered machine (Java has some big overhead in embedded places as compared to writing native code).

The answer is maybe. I've seen Java running on a machine with 4MB of RAM, but it was not running Linux (in fact there was no OS at all). Link: [Java on the Nintendo DS](http://www.volny.cz/molej/pstrosnds/)

Answer (score 4):

There is a [List of Java virtual machines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Java_virtual_machines) on Wikipedia, with a number of them open source and targeting embed devices. Like [Mika](http://www.k-embedded-java.com/mika/trac/) which seems quite small and portable.

Answer (score 1):

The [Squawk virtual machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squawk_virtual_machine) is designed for small devices. It's probably got sub-par performance though since most of it is in java.

Answer (score -1):

Probably a little late but I'd also suggest Squawk. It runs on sun spot devices which have  160k of membory (or something in that area). 160mhz CPU. The whole JVM is open source so you can try to re-write it for your own devices :)